How to Dynamically Load Language-Specific Content in JavaScript?
I'm working on a web application where I have a set of content (e.g., chat messages, text snippets) in multiple languages, and I want to dynamically load the content based on the user's language preference. I'm using JavaScript for the frontend, and I'm looking for guidance on how to implement this functionality.
var chatMessages = [{
    name: "Emily",
    msg: "<strong class='c-1'>Emily:</strong> Hey guys! Have you heard about the party at Jake's place this weekend? It's gonna be lit!",
    delay: 10,
    align: "left",
    showTime: true,
    time: "20:00"
  },
  {
    name: "Sarah",
    msg: "<strong class='c-1'>Sarah:</strong> Yeah, I'm so hyped for it! Can't wait to see everyone there.",
    delay: 600,
    align: "left",
    showTime: true,
    time: "20:01"
  },
  {
    name: "Mark",
    msg: "<strong class='c-1'>Mark:</strong> Definitely gonna be there! We gonna turn up!",
    delay: 1200,
    align: "left",
    showTime: true,
    time: "20:02"
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    msg: "Count me in, no doubt. It's gonna be a blast!",
    delay: 1200,
    align: "right",
    showTime: true,
    time: "20:03"
  }]
]['en'];


Common practice is to have different JS files with the different messages (one file per language/message set) and then load the file you need based on the language selected

There’s many localization libraries out there

@blurfus Another js file or text files?

@DanielA.White Can you guide me how?

different JS files

Can you write me an answer?
